# How to open a file dialogue box in JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

How can I get an "open file dialogue" box in JavaScript?

Comment: More context required, OS? Javascript host?

Comment: Sorry ya
i am using Asp.net in that iam generating file upload control dynamically. when i am using Mozilla iam not getting Full file path :)

Answer (score 3):

Javascript cannot open files. (Leastways not in any cross browser secure way).

Possibly you'd be interested in `<input type="file" />` (an intro [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html)).

Comment: i need only that dialogue box, i think u got me :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that no, you cannot do this through pure Javascript; the only way to do this is via an HTML form with an `<input type="file">` element.